# Null vs empty String in Firestore, any difference?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a difference between one field of type `null` and one field of type string that is empty?

In the documentation it says:

`Null`........... 1 byte

`String`.......   total of bytes with UTF-8 encode + 1

In this case, one empty string is equal to a null value?

I'm creating my database and I'm trying to avoid empty data in some cases. I don't know if it's best to declare one field as `null` when it does not have data.

Answer (score 5):

A Firestore null is a completely different data type than a Firestore string.  A null is never equal to any string. An empty string and a null might occupy the same amount of space, but that's where the similarities end.

You can even see from the [documentation on value type ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering) that they sort differently, where null always sorts "less than" any string in a query that involves different data types.

One of use of null as a document field is to make that field searchable without any actual data to index.  If a document doesn't have a field with a value, that document will not be searchable by that field.  As soon as you put a null in a field, you can query that field for equality with null.

Comment: Then, if the space is the same, is best to create the field as empty string? In some cases this field will have values, but in another cases it will have no data.

Comment: You should store an empty string if that's the data that will be useful in the future.  It's entirely up to you.  Personally, I wouldn't store an empty string to represent a lack of data - that's a common anti-pattern. Use null to represent a lack of data. Use a string to represent an actual string value that you want to use later.

Comment: Hmm.. I am currently storing urls for images, and if it's not available the field is null. However, when Firebase converts the data using toObject, the field (currently null when I check the console), is converted to a blank String. Nothing is being done extra just simply: document.toObject<T>() and the immediate object has a blank string instead of null for the image field, when I run the debugger. The field is defined as { val image: String? = null } in the class.

Comment: @ChadMx You should post an entirely new question showing the code and data that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for the direction. In attempting to gather the examples for a new question, I realised I quite literally went barking up the wrong tree as I was looking at the incorrect field path to the data in Firestore. The correct field path actually had an empty string stored and not a Null.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an empty string is equal to ""

Comment: I'm creating documents in Firestore from my database and I need to decide when one field not have data if I create this field as `null` or as empty string. This is because I map the snapshoot to one class.

Comment: It is entirely up to you. I would use an empty string just to go easily